# OFL.EXE Syntax / Documentation

Tags: documentation, files

Does anyone know where I can find the documentation, syntax, example usage for OFL.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a sample usage at [www.tburke.net](http://www.tburke.net/info/misc/ofl.htm). You may be interested in the [OpenFile Command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/openfiles.mspx?mfr=true) also.